# Disjoint union topology and homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking for some conditions to build an homeomorphism $f$ from $\bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}^\ast} \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}^\ast} \mathbb{R}^n$. I'm not familiar at all with disjoint union topology, so I need help:

1- Is it necessary that $f$ maps $(k,x)$ to an element $(k,y)$ (for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^k$) ? I think that if $f$ maps $(k,x)$ to an element $(p,y)$ where $k \neq p$, then we may have at some point a problem because $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathbb{R}^p$ are not homeomorphic. I'm not able to explain it for the moment, it's just an intuition (which might be false !).

2- Assuming that I'm able to construct a bijection $f$ such that $f$ maps $(n,x)$ to an element $(n,y)$ (for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^k$) and that I want to show that it is an homeomorphism. How can I do to proceed ? Can I use classical results about mappings from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^k$ and "discard $k$" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sets $\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n$ are the connected components of the discrete union, so $h$ must take each $\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n$ to a connected subset of $X=\bigsqcup_{n\in\Bbb N^*}\Bbb R^n$ and hence into one of the components $\{k\}\times\Bbb R^k$ for some $k$. Ss you say, these components are pairwise non-homeomorphic, so any homeomorphism $h$ of $X$ into itself must carry each component into itself, i.e., must satisfy the condition that $$h[\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n]\subseteq\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n$$ for each $n\in\Bbb N^*$. Thus, $h$ must be the union of homeomorphisms $$h_n:\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n\to\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n\;.$$

Comment: What do you mean by "$h$ must be the union of homeomorphisms $h_n$" ?

Comment: @deeppinkwater: Exactly that. $h$ is a set of ordered pairs of elements of $X$. For each $n$, some of those pairs are in $(\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n)\times(\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n)$, and the set of such pairs is $h_n$. In other words, $h_n=h\upharpoonright(\{n\}\times\Bbb R^n)$. And $h=\bigcup_nh_n$.

Comment: Ok, so regarding my second question: if I have a bijection $h$ which maps $(n,x)$ to $(n,y)$, is it sufficient to show that $h_n$ is an homeomorphism ?

Comment: @deeppinkwater: Yes, if you can show that each of the restrictions $h_n$ is a homeomorphism, then $h$ is, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: @deeppinkwater: My pleasure!